# WebSphere 8 : JAX-WS client for Axis2 WS

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, apache-axis

I am trying to write a JAX WS client for a service exposed using Axis2, WebSphere8, Java 1.6.
Standalone client(i.e. client running in my local machine) works fine but when I deploy the client in a application running in same websphere server I get 
    `java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast class org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider to class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider`
 at line  `OpenPortType service = OpenService
                .create(wsdlFile.toURL(),
                        new QName(                      "http://www.test.com/schemas/public/open-api/Open/","OpenService")).getPort(
                        OpenPortType.class);`

When I tried to google I found similar problem existed in weblogic : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-4835 
When we see source of axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider class we come to know that it's a subclass of javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider !!
I'm wondering what could be wrong ? Any idea ?

Comment: Are you packaging or explicitly calling Axis2, or are you just using JAX-WS APIs? Ideally, you shouldn't need to reference Axis2 at all but just rely on WebSphere's built-in JAX-WS support (which happens to be based on Axis2, but at least somewhat customized).

Comment: @dbreaux Thanks for the response. As you rightly mentioned, from the client project I'm not calling axis2 explicitly. I've put dependency on jsr181-api,jaxb-api, jaxws-api jars. It must be noted that the web service is exposed using Axis2 and it runs in same websphere8 instance.

Comment: What do you mean you've put a dependency on those jars? (Sorry, I haven't gotten smart on WAS8 yet.) I'd think in the EAR and WAR themselves, including in shared library configuration, you wouldn't want to point at those jars at all since they're implicitly part of WebSphere.

Comment: Those jars are part of my ear, I was not able to locate the specific jars in websphere(I do not know if websphere has it's own implementation of the jars......which might conflict with jars packaged by me)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are calling Axis2 capabilities directly, rather than simply using JAX-WS APIs, you do not want to package Axis into your EAR. WebSphere does provide its own JAX-WS implementation which I'm not surprised conflicts with another JAX-WS implementation you've deployed in your app. (In particular, note that WebSphere's own implementation is based on Axis2.)

If you do need to deploy a different implementation, you'll probably have to at least adjust your WebSphere classloader policy to parent_last. There might be more to do as well; it's been a while since we did this ourselves. But it's much easier and cleaner to use the built-in JAX-WS implementation, which means not deploying any of those jars at all.